# Best way to maintain references to a collection of generic types

Tags: c#, generics

Say I have this interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : Entity
{
  T Get(string query);
  void Save(T entity);
}
```

And I have a couple of concrete classes like (where User and Project, of course, inherit from Entity):

```
public class UserRepository : IRepository<User> { ... }
public class ProjectRepository : IProjectRepository<Project> { ... }
```

What is the best way to keep a reference to all those in a single collection?  You obviously can't have something like:

```
var repos = new IRepository<Entity>[]
{
  new UserRepository(),
  new ProjectRepository()
}
```

So *must* I have a non-generic interface from which the generic interface inherits?

```
public interface IRepository
{
  Entity Get(string query);
  void Save(Entity entity);
}

public interface IRepository<T> : IRepository { ... }
```

Thanks for any help, ideas, suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `IRepository<T>` interface doesn't really lend itself to co- or contra-variance, since `T` appears in *both* input and output positions. The best you can really do here is provide a non-generic interface as you point out.

You could, of course, store references to any type using `object` - but I'm guessing that you're looking for something more typesafe than that.

Comment: Yeah, I was handling it all in an object collection and yes, did want a more type-safe way.

Comment: Also, glad I asked, I will have to read up on the implications of ISomeInterface<out/in T>: http://blog.t-l-k.com/dot-net/2009/c-sharp-4-covariance-and-contravariance Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

> So must I have a non-generic interface from which the generic interface inherits?

Yes. You could put fewer methods on that non-generic interface, if you can get away with it: it depends how much type casting you wanted to do. (You could put them in an `object[]`, for instance.)